# Is this Fire and Forget? (Linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I have a XXXWriter. Is this the correct Fire and Forget approach in C#?

```
public void Add(XXX model)
    {
        Task.Run(() => // Fire and forget?
        {
            using (var ctx = new FormsEntities())
            {
                var dbXXX = new DALXXX();
                dbXXX.Foo = model.Foo;

                try
                {
                    ctx.DALXXX.Add(dbXXX);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Log.LogError(ex.GetMostInnerException(), "whatever");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not returning anything and doesn't appear to have side effects (aside from the DB operation), so I don't see how it could be anything else.

Comment: Is it firing? Are you forgetting about it? :)

Comment: It's fire and forget but can easily fail because the database operation isn't awaited eg if the application or web request terminates. What's the point?

Comment: If you wanted to save changes without blocking you could have used `await SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: I want to log stuff. Not so important.

Comment: @GabrielLuci is it what? :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that the implementation is refactored as below

```
public class XXXWriter
{
    public static void FireAndForget(XXX model)
    {
       Task.Run(() => DoFireAndForgetAsync(model));
    }

    private void DoFireAndForgetAsync(XXX model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new FormsEntities())
            {
                var dbXXX = new DALXXX();
                dbXXX.Foo = model.Foo;            

                ctx.DALXXX.Add(dbXXX);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
         {

            // Remember that the Async code needs to handle its own
            // exceptions, as the "DoFireAndForget" method will never fail
               Log.Log.LogError(ex.GetMostInnerException(), "whatever");

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why? What is better about your implementation? Especially if you are going to recommend `Task.Factory.StartNew` over `Task.Run`, you should explain why. But read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) first.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielLuci , i read both the articles would agree using Task.Run() is a better option. Though will stick with the function approach as i like my code to be natural and readable